# Bottom navigation + Drawer + Ads

Tags: android, admob, material-design

According to [latest guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html) for navigation bar it should be placed at the bottom of the screen, when Drawer with toolbar is placed at the top of the screen.

Taking that into account, where banner ads should be placed? According to the [ad placement guidelines](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128877?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287) it should not be placed anywhere around clickable things.
Previously with toolbar and tabhost ads could be placed at the bottom of the screen, now it seems that there is no place for the ads with such design. Is it?

Comment: interestingly enough, this contradicts the patterns discussed in the "Pure Android" section of http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html, which one to choose....

Answer (score 1):

In Admob's [documentation on adaptive banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive), the screenshots included by Google shows banner ads on top of the bottom navigation. Not a lawyer, I think it is okay to place as long as you provide enough room to click the navigation buttons and keeps other guidelines like the ads are not overlapping the views.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the ad placement guidelines are to try to limit inadvertent clicks and to rule out intentional placement of ads into areas that are likely to be confused with content or otherwise clicked on.

Use your common sense.

Comment: Sure, but with such layout commons sense tells "Don't use banner ads", what with current Google Play business model doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Well ads are not appropriate to all apps. But I don't believe that such a layout dictates that banners ads are precluded.